# How important is EntityObject?

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to create mock-up entities for testing purposes. I found many code generators for this, like:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a850e686-df08-4245-b0bb-5872654285c9

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2aa9e9a-1314-4a96-8365-81771b17c597

However, in both of them, I noticed that, unlike the default Microsoft Entity Framework generator, the entity classes are not deriving from EntityObject class!

Is there any disadvantage in that? What are the advantages of EntityObject class anyway? I checked its documentation and I didn't see any useful functionality that cannot be implemented without!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is difference between heavy weight entities and POCO entities. Heavy weight entity is derived from `EntityObject` and is tightly coupled with EF - the entity is not persistence ignorant. POCO entity is just common .NET class without any relation to persistence (EF in this case).

`EntityObject` based entities are "clever" - because they know about EF existence they are sometimes easier to use in some cases but harder to use in other cases (especially detached scenarios). Trend is to use POCOs which are available since EF 4.0.

Comment: Can you please give me examples of how EntityObject based entities are clever, and of how they are harder?!

Comment: Also, there is something that I need in the EntityObject class, which is the state of the entity (attached, detached, etc.), is that possible in POCO objects?!

Comment: The fact that entity knows its state is example of "clever", another example is "Reference" properties and EntityCollection typed navigation properties giving you more options to efficiently work with navigation properties. Example of harder is anything where you want to achieve persistence ignorance - including testing.

Comment: It is possible to get state of POCO but you must use `ObjectStateManager` accessible through `ObjectContext` instance.

Comment: Thanks very much. So from your answer, it seems that EntityObject has more advantages over POCO, so why is trend moving toward using POCOs?!

Comment: Because of persistence ignorance. Modern architecture doesn't want to have everything tightly coupled to specialized frameworks.

Comment: Yes, that seems important, but the three examples you mentioned (state, reference properties, and navigation properties) looks important, so do people find workaround those (apart from state, which you already mentioned how it can be implemented with POCO), or they just give up some of the advantages of EntityObject-based entities?

Comment: You still have navigation properties with POCO but you don't have additional information available in EntityCollection and EntityReference classes directly available. You again have to dig this information from context.

Comment: Aha, cool. I am marking your question as accepted, but it will be great if you can edit to include some of the important details discussed in the comments.